# Is there a "scientific" online source for famous direct qoutes?

Tags: writing, online-resource, quotation

I'm searching for an online source that is considered "scientific" to look up some well-known quotes such as "There's no such thing as a free lunch." (Milton Friedman).

I may want to use kind of an insinuating quote about risk in my term paper.

Comment: Be careful; it's easy for these to come off as "cutesy" or overly contrived.  If you have to search in a quotes database, odds are that including the quote is more likely to look tacky than insightful.  I'm not saying a judicious use of a great quote can never be appropriate; just that it's easier to fall short than to impress readers.

Comment: What is a “scientific source”?

Answer (score 2):

How about [Quotedb](http://www.quotedb.com/categories/science)? It seems awfully relevant although risk might be quite a specialized area to be included in it. Quotes tend to be rather general.